# Add to cart quantity reset to 1 even i added 2 qty in Arabic store Magento 2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, quantity

**Minicart** quantity reset to 1 even I added qty 2 **Magento 2**. I am having the Arabic store, in the Arabic store only this issue shows, is it the **problem with Locales**. **Please help to solve it.**

Comment: Hello, I have an idea about these things

Comment: I am also facing same issue, did you got solution . thanks in advance